# How to iterate in 1:N relationship in Dynamics CRM4 C# Plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

Our Account entity has a 1:N relationship with 'BookingAccount', a custom Entity. The name of the relationship is new_Account_new_BookingAccount. In a plug-in, if I try to iterate the collection

```
foreach (new_BookingAccount ba in myAccount.new_Account_newBookingAccount)
{
    ...
}
```

it's null - even when there are related BookingAccounts.

Am I supposed to re-query for the BookingAccounts or can I call some 'populate' method on the collection property? If so how is the best way to do this? And what's the point of the collection property if you can't iterate it.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - the collection needs to be loaded explicitly:

```
orgContext.LoadProperty(account, "new_BookingAccount_new_ExternalCode");
foreach (new_BookingAccount ba in myAccount.new_Account_new_BookingAccount)
{
    ...
}
```

(Though this can't be done if the accouont is a new entity, so needs some sort of check beforehand):

```
if (account.CreatedOn == null)
    return;
```

Seems like a lot of work for simple collection iteration

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. If you will write client with early bound entity classes, you will see that such collections leverage generic [GetRelatedEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg326130.aspx) method. Code will looks like:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// 1:N account_activity_parties
        /// </summary>
        [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.RelationshipSchemaNameAttribute("account_activity_parties")]
        public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyCrmNamespace.ActivityParty> account_activity_parties
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetRelatedEntities<MyCrmNamespace.ActivityParty>("account_activity_parties", null);
            }
            ...
        }
```

This code should work in all cases properly. Of course, there are possible some security issues. Your code executed under some CRM user credentials and you should be sure that the user has enough permissions to browse both entities.
But most important thing you should pay attention, it's how do you retrieve the instance `myAccount`. You mentioned that this code is used inside of plug in. But you didn't mentioned what kind of plug in (pre-stage, post-stage) it is, what kind of message do you handle in this plug in, how do you retrieve the instance of the entity `myAccount`. If you directly invoke retrieve method, all the properties should be populated. But if `myAccount` comes from input parameters, there is no guarantee that all actual values will be set for all properties. Might be it is the reason why the collection is empty.

Comment: Great, thank you for the advice. It's a post stage plug-in and I am getting the entity from a post image. Anything that is set/changed by the user is available (and to be certain, I changed it, saved it, then ran the plug-in) - still empty! We haven't set up security on our system yet, so don't think it is that. Thanks again for your help